# How to avoid from for loop in this python script

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am doing some data analysis task , with this python script i can get my desired results , but its very slow maybe due to for loop , i have to handle millions of data rows , is there way to change this script to fast ?

```
df=df.sort_values(by='ts')
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['ts']))
df = df.rename(columns={'ts': 'Time'})
x2=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D', base=30, label='right'))
for name, df1 in x2:
    df1_split=np.array_split(df1,2)
    df_first=df1_split[0]
    df_second=df1_split[1]
    length_1=len(df_first)
    length_2=len(df_second)
    if len(df_first)>=5000:
        df_first_diff_max=abs(df_first['A'].diff(periods=1)).max()
        if df_first_diff_max<=10:
            time_first=df_first['Time'].values[0]
            time_first=pd.DataFrame([time_first],columns=['start_time'])
            time_first['End_Time']=df_first['Time'].values[-1]
            time_first['flag']=1
            time_first['mean_B']=np.mean(df_first['B'])
            time_first['mean_C']=np.mean(df_first['C'])
            time_first['mean_D']=np.mean(df_first['D'])
            time_first['E']=df_first['E'].values[0]
            time_first['F']=df_first['F'].values[0]
            result.append(time_first)
    if len(df_second)>=5000:
        df_second_diff_max=abs(df_second['A'].diff(periods=1)).max()
        if df_second_diff_max<=10:
            print('2')
            time_first=df_second['Time'].values[0]
            time_first=pd.DataFrame([time_first],columns=['start_time'])
            time_first['End_Time']=df_second['Time'].values[-1]
            time_first['flag']=2
            time_first['mean_B']=np.mean(df_second['B'])
            time_first['mean_C']=np.mean(df_second['C'])
            time_first['mean_D']=np.mean(df_second['D'])
            time_first['E']=df_second['E'].values[0]
            time_first['F']=df_second['F'].values[0]
            result.append(time_first)

final=pd.concat(result)
```

Comment: Not the spirit of doing things this way in a parallel environment, need to do some data wrangling

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle millions of rows maybe you should try to use Hadoop or Spark if you have resources enough.

I think that analyze such amount of data in a single node is a bit crazy.

Comment: @ using hadoop , but still its slow due to for loop

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try something different with Pandas, you could try using vectorization. Here is a link to a quick overview of the time to iterate over a set of data. It looks like Numpy has the most efficient vectorization method, but the internal Pandas one might work for you as well.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06

- The Pandas Built-In Function: iterrows() — 321 times faster
- The apply() Method — 811 times faster
- Pandas Vectorization — 9280 times faster
- Numpy Vectorization — 71,803 times faster

(All according to timing the operations on a dataframe with 65 columns and 1140 rows)

Comment: always try to avoid to post link, they can expire